# OpenCV - Not able to write images to video files

Tags: python, opencv

I have such a loop to write video files from images:

```
for a in range(len(events)):
        c_videos = []
        first = events[a][0]
        last = events[a][1]
        c_videos = video_ids[numpy.where(numpy.logical_and(timestamps >= first, timestamps <= last))]
        video_name = "/export/students/sait/9-may-video-dataset/video-" + str(events[a][2]) + ".avi"
        video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name,-1,1,(width,height))
        for b in range(len(c_videos)):
                img_file = "/export/students/sait/9-may-results/rgb-" + str(c_videos[b]) + ".ppm"
                img = cv2.imread(img_file)
                video.write(img)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        video.release()
```

But I cannot become successful in creating videos. I don't see any created video file under the destination directory.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you take a look at http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/

Comment: Yes I checked. But it is not so related with my task. I have some bunch of images, and I need to create video. But this damn opencv doesnt do it, and kills my time.

Comment: Can you attach a few sample images in a way that we can reproduce what does not work?

Comment: @yusuf "this damn OpenCV" is most likely not to blame. For example, your code never checks whether `cv2.imread` succeeds. Please, include a minimal (but working) example that reproduces this issue, along with sample images. This can be just loading a single image and creating a video with a single frame.